# StatusBadDataTypeIDUnknown (0x80110000) - Read Custom Extension Object

Tags: go, opc-ua, node-opcua, qtopcua

I am trying to read custom extension object but read status not ok for this node. Do we need to registers a new extension object type
or have mechanism to register all custom extension object at a time of connection establishment to server ?

Error-
The extension object cannot be (de)serialized because the data type id is not recognized. StatusBadDataTypeIDUnknown (0x80110000)

**Note- I am using Native Go OPC-UA library to read extension objects.**

Thanks !